# JavaScript: IE 11 and MS Edge override CTRL+P

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have a problem, and can't find any solution.
I've defined custom CTRL+P shortcut with javascript in my application and I want IE 11 and MS Edge not to show their print window.
So, after my code runs I've wrote this code:

```
                e.keyCode = 0;
                e.cancelBubble = true;
                e.returnValue = false;

                if (e.preventDefault)
                    e.preventDefault();

                if (e.stopPropagation)
                    e.stopPropagation();

                return false;
```

unfortunately it doesn't work. Print window shows as well. On chrome and firefox everything works fine.
One more thing: when on Edge I'm stopping script executing (for example in line e.keyCode = 0;) with breakpoint and then resume print window will not show.

The way I'm adding custom shortcut is:

```
if (el.addEventListener) el.addEventListener('keydown', func, false);
else if(el.attachEvent) el.attachEvent('onkeydown', func);
...
```

*func* variable contains my code for custom actions and code for stop propagation (from the beginning of the message).
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reliably block the "print" dialog.

Suggestion:

Don't (attempt to) break built-in browser functionality.
This will *always* lead to a reduced UX.

Besides, even *if* you manage to disable the printing popup, what's to stop a user from taking a screenshot?

Comment: it's a business application. Users have an opportunity to define their own shortcuts.

Comment: Why would a user _ever_ use something other than [Ctrl]+[P], to print? Besides, that still doesn't change the fact it's not possible to reliably block it.

Comment: I don't know. There are different users and different situation.

Comment: Then we may as well try to capture the Windows / Mac key, in case a user wants to use those. My point: Don't try to break how the browser works.